# Can someone provide me context clues to understand the difference between these two phrases?

Tags: difference, phrase-usage

Can someone provide me context clues to understand the difference between these two phrases? When to use them?

1. How did you manage to do that?
2. How do you manage to do that?

Comment: Understanding the difference between those two phrases is merely understanding the difference between the present tense and the past tense. That's been asked and answered a million times over. It's also so basic that if you don't understand it, then you won't understand any explanation given to you in English and so should review an explanation of the difference in your native language, like in your ESL textbook.

Comment: Thanks Ben, but that’s really not helping. I'm not an ESL student, I don't have an ESL textbook. I learn almost anything from the internet. And why would you assume that I won't understand it? Because the question is "too basic"? Well I guess don't bother commenting then, it's definitely not worth your time, but thanks for dropping by.

Comment: To spell it out, (1) refers to something the person being addressed has already done, (2) to something they are doing now. The difference between _did_ and _do_ is pretty basic. (2) could also be a request for instructions how to do it.